# How to get a footer just above a Scrollviewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollview

I got a Scrollviewer with an ItemsControl inside. The ItemsControl, depending on the number of items in it, can be scrolled or not with the SCrollViewer.
I have a Control that display some total values of all the items. This control needs to be just under the ItemsControl. If there is not many items, it will be just under the last, not on the bottom of the page, with a lot of space between.
I can't achieve to do that. 
Has anyone any ideas ? Here some of my code :

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>      

<DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
    <!-- This is my Total Control - just a Border for the example -->
    <Grid Margin="0,4" MaxHeight="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Border Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>          

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      >
        <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListeQuestions}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <concUCQuest:UCQuestion HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

[Here is a link to a picture of what i try to get](http://tof.canardpc.com/view/33d72c2c-d77c-458a-9824-42a12e72debf.jpg)

I tried DockPanel, Grid into Grid, but I've got out of ideas.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does your items control not handle the scroll bars itself?  Eg if it was a list or tree view then you wouldn't need the scroll viewer.

Comment: No, it's a simple ItemsControl, intended to only display information.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` to the Scrollviewer should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't work exactly as i expect. When i got a little number of items, the "Total control" is not right above the items, cause the ScrollViewer takes a lot of void space. Thanks anyway

Comment: Scollviewer will not size ot it's contents afaik. You could calculate the height based on the number of items in your binding via a ValueConverter, and size the scrollviewer accordingly when the calculated height is below a treshold value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <!-- This is my Total Control - just a Border for the example -->
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Border Background="Red" Height="10"/>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

This works for me.

You can also use a ListBox with a DataTemplate, instead of wrapping an ItemsControl with a ScrollViewer.

Comment: Thansks, but the bottom control goes to the bottom, and not directly under the ItemsControl. For the ListBox, i thought that, but the selection of items is not what i want.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I must have read your question wrong. If you want the 'border' to always follow the bottom of the ItemsControl, you could put both of them into a stackpanel, and then make the stackpanel's height auto.